What is coefficient in simple terms? How can i identify coefficient in an algebric expression
How can I make a 12-year-old girl understand what a is coefficient and how to identify it no matter how complicated the algebraic expression is? She had not been able to identify the coefficients in the terms $\frac{4x-3}{5ay}$. So when I explained to her what are the coefficients in the mentioned expression she wasn't able to understand it. So can anyone please tell me a simple explanation to make her understand that?

Those are the numbers next to the letters. Maybe you can tell her to ask her teacher questions when she doesn't understand something.

Did your daughter just ask the same thing? Two accounts with the same last name 'Rashid' posted nearly identical questions within the hour.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I believe the question that Jon's comment is asking about is What are the coefficients in the expression $\frac{4x-3}{5}ay$.

Yes, that is the one. As a response, perhaps Mr. Douma is onto something that is simple enough for a 12 year old. Has she started solving simple linear systems yet?

@JohnDouma, let's not be mean, the OP is just someone trying to explain something to their daughter.

Before you explain to her what coefficients are in the given expression, start with something simpler.
Here's how you can do it:

Ask her to imagine each variable in an algebraic expression as a box that can hold different things. Since it's a variable you do not know what it holds, just like a box. The coefficient is the number that tells you how many of those boxes you have.

Start with simpler expressions first. For example start with the expression $5x$, the number $5$ is the coefficient because it tells us there are $5$ of the variable(box) $x$.

Now take a slightly complicated expression like $4x + 3y$ and explain what a term is in an expression. In algebra, each part of an expression separated by a plus $(+)$ or minus $(-)$ is called a term. For example, in the expression $4x + 3y$, there are two terms: $4x$ and $3y$. The coefficient is the number in front of each variable(box) in each term. So now we have $4$ boxes of type $x$ and $3$ of type $y$.

Give her some more such examples to help her identify variables, coefficients and terms in an expression.

Finally take the mentioned example and see if she's able to identify the coefficients correctly. Again, breakdown the given expression into the numerator and denominator first and ask her to identify the term in each of them. Also explain to her what constants are - numbers that do not have any variable next to them.


You could compare coefficients to counting objects in real life. If she has $4$ apples, the $"4"$ tells her how many apples she has. Similarly, in algebra, the coefficient tells how many of that variable are present. Once she understands the basics, you can continue with more complicated examples like $\frac{5}{2} x$, where the coefficient is a fraction.
Hope that helps.
